# apache phoenix range scan slower than full scan

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to optimize performance in the use of Apache Phoenix and HBase in our platform. One critical query, call it Q, requires a join between 2 tables, let's call them X and Y. X contains 150,000,000 rows, and Y contains 20,000 rows.

The explain plan for Q is the following:

> CLIENT 22-CHUNK PARALLEL 22-WAY FULL SCAN OVER X
>       some filtering
>       some aggregation   CLIENT MERGE SORT
>       PARALLEL INNER-JOIN TABLE 0
>           CLIENT 1-CHUNK PARALLEL 1-WAY SKIP SCAN ON 2 KEYS OVER Y    [11,000,000,433,043] - [11,000,000,433,115]
>               some filtering

I was able to devise another query, call it Q*, that created the same output as Q, and utilized Phoenix's Skip Scan.

The idea is to determine the necessary primary keys to execute the query before hand, and modify Q into Q* so that Phoenix can determine to use Skip Scan on the necessary primary key range.

The explain plan for Q* is the following:

> CLIENT 13-CHUNK PARALLEL 13-WAY SKIP SCAN ON 1 RANGE OVER X
>   [10,100,000,034,326,4] - [10,100,002,330,223,4]
>       some filtering
>       some aggregation   CLIENT MERGE SORT
>       PARALLEL INNER-JOIN TABLE 0
>           CLIENT 1-CHUNK PARALLEL 1-WAY SKIP SCAN ON 2 KEYS OVER Y    [11,000,000,433,043] - [11,000,000,433,115]
>               some filtering

However, when testing the performance of these 2 queries, I found that Q* took about 1.5x as long as Q on average.
Results:

Q* results: avg: 9739 | min: 9174 | max: 11117

Q results: avg: 6393 | min: 6128 | max: 6966

I can see that Q* is using less threads than Q, but that makes sense as Q* reads less chunks than Q. So I do not think this is the cause.

However, it is possible that the operation necessary to determine the primary key range for Q* (this is also a phoenix query) is the primary culprit, but I am not convinced.

Any insight on the inner workings of Phoenix which explains this lack of improved performance for a seemingly more efficient HBase operation is appreciated.

Example phoenix queries Q and Q* are below.

Thanks in advance.

Q:

```
SELECT  AH.date,   
    M.groupKey,     AH.classType,   
    AH.prodType,     AH.liabType,     AH.feeType,   
    AH.currency,     SUM(AH.feeAccrued),   
    SUM(AH.accruedAmt),     SUM(AH.totalMktValue),   
           SUM(AH.mktValue),     SUM (AH.cashFlowAmt),   
           SUM(AH.wtCashFlowAmt),     SUM(0) AS uvAmount  
         FROM **X** AH   JOIN **Y** M   
         ON M.accountKey       = AH.accountKey  
         WHERE M.groupKey IN (11000000433043,11000000433115)  
         AND AH.accountKey   =M.accountKey  
         AND classType= 4  
         AND AH.date > 20021231  
         AND AH.date <= 20171030     
         AND (AH.deleteFlag IS NULL OR AH.deleteFlag = 'N')   
         AND AH.reconFlag = 'Y'  AND AH.reconActivity = 'Y'   
          AND M.etlTag = 'TEST'   
         GROUP BY AH.date,   
           M.groupKey ,     AH.classType,   
           AH.prodType,     AH.liabType,     AH.feeType,   
           AH.liabType,AH.currency
```

Q*:

```
SELECT  AH.date,   
    M.groupKey,     AH.classType,   
    AH.prodType,     AH.liabType,     AH.feeType,   
    AH.currency,     SUM(AH.feeAccrued),   
    SUM(AH.accruedAmt),     SUM(AH.totalMktValue),   
           SUM(AH.mktValue),     SUM (AH.cashFlowAmt),   
           SUM(AH.wtCashFlowAmt),     SUM(0) AS uvAmount  
         FROM **X** AH   JOIN **Y** M   
         ON M.accountKey       = AH.accountKey  
         WHERE M.groupKey IN (11000000433043,11000000433115)  
         AND AH.accountKey   =M.accountKey  
         ***AND AH.accountKey <= 10100002330223   
         AND AH.accountKey >= 10100000034326***  
         AND classType= 4  
         AND AH.date > 20021231  
         AND AH.date <= 20171030     
         AND (AH.deleteFlag IS NULL OR AH.deleteFlag = 'N')   
         AND AH.reconFlag = 'Y'  AND AH.reconActivity = 'Y'   
          AND M.etlTag = 'TEST'   
         GROUP BY AH.date,   
           M.groupKey ,     AH.classType,   
           AH.prodType,     AH.liabType,     AH.feeType,   
           AH.liabType,AH.currency
```

Comment: MergeSort tells me you might want to look at query hints and tweak the type of join to optimize the phoenix query. https://phoenix.apache.org/joins.html.